# Anyone familiar with Helicon URL rewriter here? I need to know if we can create MapFiles in some drive

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I need to know if we can create MapFiles in some different or do we HAVE to create it in Helicon folder only?

Like my Helicon folder is installed in c:Programfiles that I do not have access to and I need to create this mapfile.txt there but I am unable to coz of no "write rights". so I was thinking may be I could somehow do some setting in IIS and create this mapfile somewhere else like in D: ? and access from there. Please help. Thanks.

**edit
@Variant
I already see a ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file as hidden file in my Project's root folder. I actually need to know if I can save the "MAPFile" too there in my project itself? How will I like set its path or whatever so my code works fine? I mean its picking up the path of this map file automatically or something. Should I manually save this file in my website's root folder or what? How do i go about it?**

***edit 2***

@Variant

This is the rule that is there in my Helicon's configuration file

```
#MapFile Start
#RewriteMap mapfile txt:mapfile1.txt  [NC]
RewriteMap mapfile txt:mapfile2.txt  [NC]

#Map File End
```

I want to know where will it search for these two mapfiles?? If I save them in my website's root folder, then will these 2 be used or the ones in C:/Programfiles/Helicon/ISAPIRewrite/ folder??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know if we can create MapFiles in some different or do we
>   HAVE to create it in Helicon folder only?

Yes, you can:

```
RewriteMap examplemap txt:C:/path/to/file/map.txt
```

From **[Official documentation](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/RewriteMap.htm):**

> **Syntax: RewriteMap MapName MapType:MapSource**
>
> Path to **MapSource** file could be either absolute or relative.
>   **Relative path is calculated from the folder with current configuration
>   file**, i.e. from the configuration file path where this map has been
>   declared.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the `httpd.ini` file in the website's root folder as well.

See here: http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/#conffile

Comment: I already see a ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file as hidden file in my Project's root folder. I actually need to know if I can save the "MAPFile" too there in my project itself? How will I like set its path or whatever so my code works fine? I mean its picking up the path of this map file automatically or something. Should I manually save this file in my website's root folder or what? How do i go about it?

Comment: The way the isapi filter works is first looking in the helicon folder, processing the file there, afterwards it looks in the individual website's root, and overriding the configuration with the file it finds there.

Comment: oh so it will use the MapFile that is there in my website's root folder? Also I need to save my map file in the website's root only? I cant in some sub folder of the webiste?

Comment: Actually I have never used a file named `mapfile.txt`, I always use `httpd.ini` which always worked for me (Since v.2 when it was the standart). Only after reading your question I learned that you can also use `mapfile.txt`